# How to force a project to refresh projections in QGIS 3.22

Tags: qgis

I have a number of QGIS projects that are based on various combinations of 20 Spatialite DBs (probably 150 tables) and over 200 scanned maps as GPKG. It's all in the province of Saskatchewan, so I try to save everything as EPSG 26913: NAD83 UTM zone 13.

Over time somehow some of my layers have been saved in other projections and I frequently get messages when I open a project saying "used a ballpark transform from EPSG:26913 to EP4326", or other. Sometimes I will go hunting for which layer it is and then I will save it as a new layer in the proper projection. Typically I will save it to the same filename in a different directory, close the project, move the file over to where it should be, and reopen the project.

What I've only just realized, after doing this dozens of times, is that if you then check the project it will still show the layer as being in the old projection. To get it to recognize the new projection I can delete it and re-add it to the project, but any particular layer may be in a dozen projects.

So... is there any way to force a project to refresh all of its references? I always assumed it checked the projection when opening the layer, but it seems that it only does that when adding a layer to the project. That seems like a really poorly thought out optimization!